# Custom Highlight Visual Studio code Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to change the highlight color of some tokens but I can't seem to figure it out. I have an installed theme which highlights class name definitions with yellow and I do like it, it also highlights built-in types in yellow. I was wondering if I could have the instances of my own classes to be highlighted with yellow as well once defined

[Brief visual description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKkNO.png)

Comment: the blue MyClass is a function call not a type

Comment: I know, bud I didn't mean that. I mean that if there's any way to have instances of a class highlighted (in the example I have defined x as an object of MyClass, so what I want is to have from now on x highlighted in yellow)

Comment: what is `int.say()`?

Comment: Python is a duck-typed language, on the next line you can assign a string to `x`. That is valid Python.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_creating-your-own-color-theme "_I was wondering if I could have the instances of my own classes_" I'm not sure if this is possible. I don't think a textmate grammar can make distinctions between which classes are your and which aren't.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`

[image]

Move the mouse to the front of the `X`,

[image]

Add the following settings in ***settings.json***, where `scope` is configured as the scope obtained in the previous step.

```json
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Abyss]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "name": "Change X to yellow",
                    "scope": "variable.other.readwrite",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#FFEEBB",
                    }
                }
            ],
        },
    },
```

Repeat the first step command, place the mouse in `MyClass` to get the color code. Then copy the color to `foreground`.

[image]

*In this example, the subject is **Abyss**.*