# How can I change the color of Python's "global" keyword in VS Code?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

I want to change the color of this keyword in python:

```py
global
```

but I don't know how to change it in my settings.json file.

Here is my the tokenColorCustomizations part of my vscode settings.json file:

```json
{
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "comments": "#00af0c",
        "strings": "#c7884a",
        "variables": "#91e2ff",
        "functions": "#fff07a",
        "keywords": "#d981ff",
        "types": "#ff73d3",
        "numbers": "#beffac",
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "keyword.operator",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#786831"
                }
            },
            {
                "scope": [
                    "source.python",
                    "punctuation.definition.variable.python"
                ],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffcaca"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me? ChatGPT was no help at all. I also already tried some other scopes, but they did not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75697351/custom-highlight-visual-studio-code-python/75717602#75717602

Answer (score 0):

You want the TextMate scope `storage.modifier.declaration.python`. Ex.

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Your Theme Name Here]": { // TODO. Or remove this wrapper to apply regardless of current theme
        "textMateRules": [{
            "scope": "storage.modifier.declaration.python",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000", // TODO
                // "fontStyle": "bold",
            },
        }],
    },
},
```

Next time use the scope inspector by running `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). See also [the official syntax highlighting docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide) and [VS Code's builtin Python TextMate grammar](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/python/syntaxes/MagicPython.tmLanguage.json).

Answer (score 0):

What about these:

```py
in
is
((())) # different parentheses colors
None
import module # the module name
```